# Using Save symbol to style for layer with Unique Values style in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, style, unique-value, categorized-renderer

I'm new to ArcGIS Pro and this process is really easy and straightforward in QGIS but in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 seems to be complicated.

I want to save the symbology of this counties layer which shows a single county in yellow and the rest with white border only.

[image]

The function is like this with a Single Symbol-styled layers
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused with the terminology; in your screen shot above you show an option to save a symbol to a style. The key point here it is a symbol, note it's in the *singular*.

If you want to share a symbol that can be accessed in all future ArcGIS Pro projects then you need to create style file to store your symbol. You create an empty style file on the Insert tab > Styles.

[image: Insert tab]

You can then shove as many symbols as you like into this. These will then be available under the Gallery section on the Symbol Pane. Below I created a style called test and loaded it with symbols bob and bob2.

[image: Test Style]

This is all different to the fact you have classified your data based upon the field NAME_2, symbolising yellow for one value and utilising all other values to create your red box effect. If you want to save the classification and reuse that then you select the layer in table of contents right click and go to Sharing > Save as Layer file. You can then use that layer file to apply your *Classification* to a future layer.

So think about the Gallery, you have literally hundreds of *symbols* you can select from but not a single symbol is a classification, you can only ever apply a symbol to your data one at a time.

A classification could be single, unique or graduated where each value has it's own symbol.